# Is there SQLAlchemy dialect support JDBC?

Tags: sqlalchemy, apache-superset

I want to connect Superset to a database by a JDBC driver. But from what I find there is no a SQLAlchemy dialect ready for this purpose. The closest option may be **jaydebeapi** but it does not have a SQLAlchemy dialect either.

Is there a way from SQLAlchemy DB Engine to connect a database through JDBC driver? Or is there a way to use JDBC driver in Superset?

Comment: The [sqlalchemy-JDBCapi](https://github.com/daneshpatel/sqlalchemy-jdbcapi) project implements SQLAlchemy dialect for supporting generic JDBC connections.

Answer (score 12):

This something I keep coming up against - it's a real shame that neither the SQLAlchemy project nor the JayDeBeAPI project want to cross this bridge.

It would automatically enable so much additional functionality in any tool that chooses SQLAlchemy like Superset.

I understand that SQL Alchemy needs a deeper understanding of the specific DB's SQL dialect for it's ORM functionalty, but it should be fairly simple to implement a mostly functional generic JDBC layer and/or inherit the existing dialects.

The most up to date reference I can find is this:

[JayDeBeAPI Comment](https://answers.launchpad.net/jaydebeapi/+question/243506)

Comment: Although this is not an answer, but I can't agree more on your comment. It is surprised to know SQLAlchemy does not have direct JDBC support and  JayDeBeAPI does not have a dialect after 3 years. Not mean to complain.

Comment: We are grappling with this puzzle at this moment. So sqlalchemy exist for apache ignite, which we are trying to connect to Superset

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the JDBC API was released fairly recently (October 2020):

https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-jdbcapi/