# How to connect Superset with Apache-ignite?

Tags: ignite, apache-superset

Has anyone tried connecting superset with Apache ignite ?

I do not known how to text 'SQLAlchemy URI', anyone can help me?

Comment: Do you mean AWS Athena or Apache Ignite?

Comment: Apache Ignite, I want to add ignite database in Superset, but I do not known how to type SQLAlchemy URI.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like no, not currently: [Is there SQLAlchemy dialect support JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407988/is-there-sqlalchemy-dialect-support-jdbc)

SQLAlchemy cannot into JDBC.

Comment: [Someone say Superset supports JDBC](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/5577), I have asked question to superset github issue, hope to get a reply.