# Data from Sybase image column truncated at 32 KiB when retrieved via pyodbc

Tags: python, database, blob, pyodbc, sybase

I have PDF files stored as image datatype (large binary data as mentioned in the doc) in a sybase database table. I am trying to read one of those files from the db and write it to a file in a local folder using python pyodbc package like this example :

```
 driver = "FreeTDS"
 prt = 'port'
 db = 'db'
 passwd = 'passwd'
 usr = 'usr'
 serv = 'serv'
 conn = pyodbc.connect(driver=driver, server=serv, port=prt, uid=usr, pwd=passwd)
 sql_query = (
    "SELECT ARCH_DOC_DOC as file_content FROM table_name WHERE ARCH_DOC_ID = id"
 )
 cursor = conn.cursor()
 cursor.execute(sql_query)
 pdf_data = cursor.fetchone()[0]
 with open('my_test_file.pdf', 'wb') as f:
     f.write(pdf_data)
```

I am using TDS driver and running this code on  Debian GNU/Linux 11 machine

```
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                            Version: freetds v1.2.3
             freetds.conf directory: /etc/freetds
     MS db-lib source compatibility: no
        Sybase binary compatibility: yes
                      Thread safety: yes
                      iconv library: yes
                        TDS version: auto
                              iODBC: no
                           unixodbc: yes
              SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                           Kerberos: yes
                            OpenSSL: no
                             GnuTLS: yes
                               MARS: yes
```

The problem is that I am getting corrupt file in the end and after testing a couple of files I noticed that I am always getting a file size 33ko. For example, the original file size that I am using to test is 90ko in the db and the file I am getting is only 33ko. So I am wondering if the issue is in the database/driver config or if there is a limit in the size of data that I can read with pyodbc ? And how can I fix that ?

Comment: If you do `hd -n 8 my_test_file.pdf` does it display something like `|%PDF-1.4|`? In other words, is the (partial) file simply truncated or is it more seriously damaged? Also, what version of pyodbc are you using?

Comment: Yes when i do `head -n 8 my_test_file.pdf` it display something like this :
`%PDF-1.4
%����
6 0 obj
<< /Creator (HP Exstream Version 8.6.106 64-bit)
/CreationDate (D:20190218022622ZZ)`. I think the file is truncated and i am getting only first chunk or something like that.
The version of pyodbc : **4.0.35**

Comment: I was able to reproduce your issue with unixODBC 2.3.6, FreeTDS 1.2.3, and pyodbc 4.0.39. The byte array retrieved by pyodbc was consistently truncated at exactly 32768 bytes. Upgrading to the latest version of FreeTDS (1.3.18) did not resolve the issue. Neither did upgrading to the latest version of unixODBC (2.3.11). Building FreeTDS without `--enable-sybase-compat` also didn't fix it, nor did using SAP's ODBC driver for ASE on Linux (libsybdrvodb-sqllen8.so). You may want to open a pyodbc issue [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/).

Comment: Thank you for the testing. I opened a pyodbc [issue](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/1226) and I hope this will be fixed soon. Is there a solution with another package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a reproducible issue, discussed here

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/1226

As a workaround, we can use [JayDeBeApi](https://pypi.org/project/jaydebeapi/) and [jTDS](https://jtds.sourceforge.net/), like so:

```py
import jaydebeapi

cnxn = jaydebeapi.connect(
    "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver",
    "jdbc:jtds:sybase://192.168.0.199:5000/mydb;useLOBs=false",
    ["sa", "myPassword"],
    "/home/gord/Downloads/jtds-1.3.1.jar"
    )
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
crsr.execute("SELECT ARCH_DOC_DOC FROM so76408133 WHERE ARCH_DOC_ID = 1")
pdf_data = crsr.fetchone()[0]
with open("test_pdf", "wb") as f:
    f.write(pdf_data)
```

Note that this requires a Java Runtime Environment (JRE). On Ubuntu/Debian, it can be installed via

```
sudo apt install default-jre
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution ! I tested using JayDeBeApi and jTDS and it works !! I am getting the whole file now.

Comment: Hello @GordThompson! Do you have any idea if this workaround could be implemented with sqlalchemy ? I only found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407988/is-there-sqlalchemy-dialect-support-jdbc) in stackoverflow  but this doesn't seem to work.